# Why error "Segmentation fault 11" occurs and how to fix it in C?

Tags: c

Function called readStudents should:

- read the number of entries from the top of the file to the formal parameter entry size (in the function signature below). Entry size is very first line of file which as some integer number that I already scanned
- create an array of type student using malloc with the right size
- continue reading student entries from file into this student array
- return a pointer to the student array.

File format is as follows:

```
   Name Surname ID Grade
   Name Surname ID Grade
   ...
```

My implementation of task is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
   char firstName[30], secondName[30];
   int ID;
   int grade;
} student;

student *readStudents(char *fileName, int* entry_size, int all_ids[], int* studentSize){ 
/*
all_ids is an array for counting the amount of grades per student. studentSize is the actual number of students (for example, in students1.txt it is 2)
*/
    FILE *openedFile = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if(openedFile == NULL){
       printf("A problem occured with opening of file");
       return 0;
    }

    char entrySize[10];
    fscanf(openedFile, "%[^\n]", entrySize);

    int numberOfEntries = atoi(entrySize);
    *entry_size = numberOfEntries;
    int i;
    student *students[i];
    *students = malloc(numberOfEntries * sizeof *students);
    for(i=1; !feof(openedFile); i++){
        fscanf(openedFile, "%s %s %i %i", students[i]->firstName, students[i]->secondName, 
        &(students[i]->ID), &(students[i]->grade));
    }

    return students;
}

int main(){
   int entrySize = 0;
   int allIds = 0;
   int studentSize = 0;
   student *studentsArray[entrySize];
   *studentsArray = readStudents("students1.txt", &entrySize, &allIds, &studentSize);

   int k;
   for(k=0; k<entrySize; k++){
      printf("%s %s %i %i \n", studentsArray[k]->firstName, studentsArray[k]->secondName, studentsArray[k]->ID, studentsArray[k]->grade);
   }    
}
```

After compiling and running it, it shows "Segmentation fault: 11".

Comment: `int entrySize = 0;` `student *studentsArray[entrySize];` you're making a VLA of size `0`.

Comment: @Blaze I changed `int entrySize` to another value of natural number though program still does not work the way it should

Comment: @user3121023 but in order to print out the contents of the file shouldn't I use loop in which every element of array should provided by its index

Comment: @user3121023 Same error"Segmentation fault: 11" shows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pointer instead of an array of pointers should work.
`malloc` will allocate memory for the number of structure that can be accessed with array notation `[i]`.
`feof` generally does not work well as a condition for file reading. Instead limit the loop to the number of structures allocated and make sure 4 items are read by fscanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char firstName[30], secondName[30];
    int ID;
    int grade;
} student;

student *readStudents(char *fileName, int* entry_size, int *all_ids, int* studentSize){
/*
all_ids is an array for counting the amount of grades per student. studentSize is the actual number of students (for example, in students1.txt it is 2)
*/
    FILE *openedFile = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if(openedFile == NULL){
        perror ( fileName);
        exit ( 0);
    }

    char entrySize[10];
    fscanf(openedFile, " %9[^\n]", entrySize);

    int numberOfEntries = atoi(entrySize);
    *entry_size = numberOfEntries;
    int i;
    student *students;
    if ( NULL == ( students = malloc(numberOfEntries * sizeof *students))) {
        perror ( "malloc students");
        exit ( 0);
    }
    for(i=0; i < numberOfEntries; i++){
        if ( 4 != fscanf(openedFile, "%29s %29s %d %d"
        , students[i].firstName
        , students[i].secondName
        , &students[i].ID
        , &students[i].grade)) {
            exit ( 0);
        }
    }
    fclose ( openedFile);
    return students;
}

int main(){
    int entrySize = 0;
    int allIds = 0;
    int studentSize = 0;
    student *studentsArray;
    studentsArray = readStudents("students1.txt", &entrySize, &allIds, &studentSize);

    int k;
    for(k=0; k<entrySize; k++){
        printf("%s %s %d %d \n"
        , studentsArray[k].firstName
        , studentsArray[k].secondName
        , studentsArray[k].ID
        , studentsArray[k].grade);
    }
    free ( studentArray);
}
```